# Tkinter draw jpeg or png

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

Is it possible to draw a *PNG* or *JPEG* image to a `tkinter.Canvas()` without using any external packages, like **PIL**?

I would like to do something, like this:

```
canvas.create_image(x, y, image="some_png_image.png")
```

Or is it possible to convert the image to *GIF*, using only built-in packages?

Comment: What do you mean by "draw a PNG or JPEG image"? Do you mean add an image to the canvas, or use the canvas to create a png image?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear — and you're actually asking two different ones.

Comment: I'm working on a GUI in Tkinter, where the user is able to upload an image, as his/her profile picture. And I vould like to display this picture. The user usually uploads PNG or JPEG file, but I can't images with this extension with Tkinter Canvas. So I need to use other library or I need to convert the file to *.gif format

Comment: PNG is supported by built-in `PhotoImage` class.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Tkinter documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), the PhotoImage class can only load images from GIF and PGM files. To load an image of another type, or to convert the image to a GIF, you'll need an external package such as OpenCV or PIL.